# I don't understand the Twilio URL Parameter on Voice

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I understand the purpose of this for more complex functionality, but I'm trying to make a simple app that does nothing more than forwards to a phone number. I don't want to hard code the forward via a Twimlet because I want to build a web app that dynamically allows me to assign the numbers. Can someone tell me what I'd put for URL parameter in this situation?

```
get '/forward-call' do
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new

  @call = @client.account.calls.create(
    {:to => "+15127778888",
    :from => "+15122222222",
    :url => "What in the foo should I put here?"})
end
```

Comment: Does this answer you question?  http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Does your `/forward-call` endpoint get called when someone makes a call to your Twilio number?

If so, you don't want to be calling the REST API right now, you want to respond to the webhook with some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml). In your case, you'd want something like this:

```
get '/forward-call' do
  content_type 'text/xml'
  "<Response>
    <Dial><Number>#{NUMBER_TO_FORWARD_TO}</Number></Dial>
  </Response>"
end
```

Does that help at all? Let me know if I can help out any more at all.

Comment: Wow, knowing that I can place Twiml directly in the Sinatra app is a game changer for me. Thank you!

Side note for others - I used this code and it didn't work at all. Then I realized that @philnash was using a GET while my previous code was a POST that I hadn't changed in the Twilio number properties. ALWAYS be wary of which you're actually calling.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!